# understanding goal exec in maven

Tags: maven, javafx-8, maven-3, exec-maven-plugin

I'm trying to create a native installer for javafx 8 application using the fxlauncher as explained at http://fxldemo.tornado.no/

In the `pom.xml` provided with the example, I do not understand what the    execution `embed-manifest-in-launcher` is doing.

**Question**: Could someone please explain whats happening there?

The first execution is straight forward, it has specified a java class which has main method and provided the arguments.

```
<execution>
    <id>create-manifest</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>java</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>fxlauncher.CreateManifest</mainClass>
        <arguments>
            <argument>${app.url}</argument>
            <argument>${app.mainClass}</argument>
            <argument>${app.dir}</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>

<!-- Embed app.xml inside fxlauncher.xml so we don't need to reference app.xml 
    to start the app -->
<execution>
    <id>embed-manifest-in-launcher</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <executable>jar</executable>
        <workingDirectory>${app.dir}</workingDirectory>
        <arguments>
            <argument>uf</argument>
            <argument>fxlauncher.jar</argument>
            <argument>app.xml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: There is a lot of "magic" happening inside that pom.xml, but as there will be called the "javapackager", i would suggest to use the [`javafx-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) for JavaFX-development using maven. For example projects, please have a look at the [test-projects](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/it). **Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of that maven-plugin.

Comment: @FibreFoX   I was able to build an installer using the plugin you specified. But I'm not able to set the jnlp out file name . Here is the link to the question on So regarding the same         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758949/how-to-specify-the-jnlp-output-file-when-using-javafx-maven-plugin-for-creating

Comment: I provided a solution on that question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment just above the execution is already providing a first hint:

> Embed app.xml inside fxlauncher.xml so we don't need to reference app.xml to start the app

The `executable` configuration entry is set to `jar`, so it will run the `jar` command.

It will then pass to it the parameters `uf`, from the [jar help](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) command we can see that:

```
-u update existing archive
-f specify archive file name
```

Hence, the `f` option is also expecting a parameter, which is indeed the `fxlauncher.jar` entry.

As such, the full command which will be executed would be:

```
jar uf fxlauncher.jar app.xml
```

Which will update the existing and provided `fxlauncher.jar` file adding to the `app.xml` file, as per comment above.

Such execution has a binding to the `package` phase in a project with packaging `jar` (the [default one](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates), hence no need to specify it), which will be executed after the [default bindings](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.2/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging) to this packaging for this phase (the Maven Jar Plugin, for instance). Hence the build will firstly create/package the jar file, then run these executions to change/update it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation