# How to specify the JNLP output file when using javafx-maven-plugin for creating a javafx native installer?

Tags: maven, javafx

I'm using the maven plugin  https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin to generate an installer for the javafx application. I could create a exe and run it successfully. the problem is I'm not able to generate the jnlp file.
I see the below message

```
[INFO] Skipping WebStart JNLP Bundler because of configuration error No OutFile Specificed
Advice to Fix: Please specify the name of the JNLP Outut file in 'jnlp.outfile'
```

Where and how to do I set the name of the JNLP output file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For having JNLP-files being generated, you have to adjust your configuration a bit:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.zenjava.test.Main</mainClass>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <appName>YourAwesomeProject</appName>
        <bundleArguments>
            <!-- to include "dtjava.js" and other related files, set this to TRUE -->
            <jnlp.includeDT>true</jnlp.includeDT>

            <!-- the JNLP-bundler needs this, they don't use "appName" for the filename ... you have to set this, otherwise it doesn't build -->
            <!-- for details of that JNLP-bundler, please have a look at the source -->
            <!-- https://github.com/Debian/openjfx/blob/e32fd960e20c58c9b7db27e426b4bca6d52add2f/modules/fxpackager/src/main/java/com/oracle/tools/packager/jnlp/JNLPBundler.java#L84 -->
            <jnlp.outfile>YourAwesomeProject</jnlp.outfile>
        </bundleArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You need to call `mvn jfx:native` instead of `mvn jfx:web` because Oracle is moving the JNLP-generation to a new internal form, removing some com.sun.*-packages.

To only have the JNLP being generated, you could reduce build-time by specifying `<bundler>jnlp</bundler>` inside the configuration.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of that maven-plugin.

Comment: I'm able to deploy the javafx app with web start using the javafx-maven-plugin.but when I add other dependency(fontawesome jar) to pom,the jar is copied to lib directory. path to the jar in the jnlp file is <jar href="lib\fontawesomefx-8.9.jar"size="571068" download="null" />  which results in an error xitException[ 3]com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://localhost:8080/installer/lib\fontawesomefx-8.9.jar.when I modify the path by changing the backward slash to a forward slash it works .Correct path http://localhost:8080/installer/lib/fontawesomefx-8.9.jar

Comment: might be a bug, I've opened a bug-ticket for that to analyse: https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/182

Comment: @user68883 Just that you know, it's a bug inside the JDK itself, I'll be creating a workaround for this ;) thanks for the catch !

Comment: Also how do we sign the jar ? when I try to sign using the maven-jarsigner-plugin it signs the original jar created by maven but doesn't sign the jar file ending with -fx.jar (The jar that's created by this plugin)? How do we sign the jar and all the dependencies ?

Comment: @user68883 I'll have to take a look into the new bundler, maybe I've to adjust the javafx-maven-plugin to sign that files. They were signed using another maven-goal `mvn jfx:web`, but that class is going to get dropped (as i mentioned in the answer to this SO-question). Currently there seems to be nothing easy. Will open another issue on the project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105402/discussion-between-user68883-and-fibrefox).