# JavaFX Web Start failure – FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource:

Tags: java, javafx-8, web-deployment, java-web-start, jnlp

I have deployed JavaFX app to web. At local host works fine only *applet*. Runned from a file works both – *applet and web start*.

But after deploying to web server I got this *exception* (probably for both of them):

Ignored exception: ExitException[ 3]com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: file:/C:/Users/Jan/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/IE/jar/myapp.jar

JNLP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="myapp.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <vendor>MeSoft</vendor>
    <description>MyApp</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="..\jar\myapp.jar" size="63799"/>
  </resources>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="600" height="600" main-class="myapp"  name="MyApp" />
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: *"Problem is somewhere in relative URLs."* What is the `codebase` of that application? See under [JNLP File Syntax: `jnlp` Element](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#jnlp) for details on the `docbase`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin).

Please have a closer look at the jar-path: `<jar href="..\jar\myapp.jar" size="63799"/>`

The problem is the `href`-part, because it contains backslashes which is not converted to slashes on linux-webservers.

When using the javafx-maven-plugin, this already [got reported](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/182) and I have created a workaround for this, but I still need to open an issue on the java bugtracker ;)

Even on SO this was reported: [How to specify the JNLP output file when using javafx-maven-plugin for creating a javafx native installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758949/how-to-specify-the-jnlp-output-file-when-using-javafx-maven-plugin-for-creating/35773771?noredirect=1#comment59234018_35773771)

Comment: Just for reference, this got already reported, but marked as "incomplete": http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8144165

Comment: Thank you for advice. Normal slashes solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

As FibreFoX said... Try using

```
${file.separator}
```

instead of 'slash'

Comment: These separators are generated because the internal tools provided by oracle are generated using RelativeFileSet, which contain os-specific separators, so it's no mistake of the user.